# Is $p(x) = \max(p_1(x), p_2(x))$ a seminorm when $p_1, p_2$ are seminorms?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

To start: I've shown that yes, $p(x) = \max(p_1(x), p_2(x))$ is a seminorm if $p_1, p_2$ are seminorms. But I did that by proving absolute homogeneity and the triangle inequality directly. What I'd like to know: Is there some broader theoretical result that could be used instead?

By way of comparison: if $\pi_i(x_1, x_2) = x_i$ are projection operators and $T$ is a linear transformation, then I know that $q(x) = p_1(\pi_1(Tx)) + p_2(\pi_2(Tx)))$ is a seminorm without directly proving the seminorm axioms because each $p_i(\pi_1(Tx))$ is a seminorm (as the composition of a seminorm and a linear operator), so that $q$ is the sum of seminorms. Is there some similar theorem(s) I could use for $p$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can ask the following more general question: if $p_1, \dots p_n$ are seminorms on some real vector space $V$, what conditions does a function $f : \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ need to satisfy so that $f(p_1, \dots p_n)$ is always a seminorm?

(Edit: throughout I assume that $f$ is nondecreasing, see the comments.)

Well, if we take $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $p_i(x_1, \dots x_n) = |x_i|$, we see that (edit: assuming that $f$ is nondecreasing, see the comments) $f$ needs to be absolutely homogeneous and subadditive. Conversely if $f$ is absolutely homogeneous and subadditive then $f(p_1, \dots p_n)$ is clearly also a seminorm.

So the answer is quite nice: $f$ itself needs to be a seminorm! The only detail that needs to be noted here is that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n$ rather than a real vector space but this isn't a big deal. There is a generalized definition of a seminorm lurking here which has the very nice property that a composition of two generalized seminorms is a generalized seminorm.

Comment: I believe that $f$ also needs to be nondecreasing in the sense that
$$x_i \le y_i, \text{ for } 1 \le i \le n \implies f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \le f(y_1,\ldots,y_n).$$
Then for $x,y \in V$ by using subadditivity we have
\begin{align}
f(p_1(x+y),\ldots,p_n(x+y)) &\le f(p_1(x)+p_1(y), \ldots, p_n(x)+p_n(y)) \\
&\le f(p_1(x), \ldots, p_n(x)) + f(p_1(y), \ldots, p_n(y)).
\end{align}
[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3198682/144766) seems to provide a counterexample otherwise.

Comment: @mechanodroid: ah, thank you. In the generalization I have in mind this is a natural extra condition to require.